# Check if key exists in JSON response within map function

Tags: javascript, json

For instance, I receive a JSON response:

```
[
  {
    'key_1': 'value1A',
    'key_2': 'value2A',
    'key_3': 'value3A'
  },
  {
    'key_1': 'value1B',
    'key_2': 'value2B',
  }
]
```

As observed, `key_3` wasn't provided in the second element of the array. Here the `keys` are the same for each object within the array.

Lets say, I am interested in only using `key_2` and `key_3` of the response and hence I use `map` as follows

```
this.serv.getInfo(code) // HTTP GET service
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res.map(el => { // only use necessary key:value pairs
      let _out = { // make an object to return

        'new_key_1': el.key_2
        'new_key_2': '' // if there is no key_3 then leave it empty

      }
      if ('key_3' in el) { // if this pair exists then add it..

        _out['new_key_2'] = el.key_3
        return _out;

      }

      return _out; // if not return with empty string
    });
  });
```

This works well as the JSON Response is small in this case. But I assume the `if(.. in el)` checks may increase many fold if the JSON structure would be large and complex.

What operator would be best suited in this case for a more *dynamic* check when mapping the response to a new object. Is there even a necessity to create a temp `_opt` object within the `map` function?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `el['key_3'] || ''` which is known as  [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation).

### DEMO

```js
let data = [
  {
    'key_1': 'value1A',
    'key_2': 'value2A',
    'key_3': 'value3A'
  },
  {
    'key_1': 'value1B',
    'key_2': 'value2B',
  }
],
  arr = data.map((el) => {
    return {'key_1': el['key_2'], 'key_2': el['key_3'] || ''};
  });

console.log(arr);
```

However it does not cover cases where `el['key_3']` equals `null`,`undefined`, `false`, `0`.

If this is unacceptable, then the `in` operator is the only way to really determine if a key within an object exist. You could use it with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and thus avoid the use of a temporary object - see demo

### DEMO

```js
let data = [
  {
    'key_1': 'value1A',
    'key_2': 'value2A',
    'key_3': 'value3A'
  },
  {
    'key_1': 'value1B',
    'key_2': 'value2B',
    'key_3': undefined,
  }
],
  arr = data.map((el) => {
    return {'key_1': el['key_2'], 'key_2': 'key_3' in el ? el['key_3'] : ''};
  });

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You need to take care with the `||`  because it does not _"check"_ if the key exists but it the value recieved is falsy. So if `null` or `0`  are stored as value then those values will be ignored and replaced by `''`. So it evaluates to  `el['key_3']`  if the value returned for `key_3`  is truthy and not if the key exists.

Comment: @t.niese good catch! if those cases have to be covered `typeof el['key_3'] != "undefined" ? el['key_3'] : '';` should be used instead

Comment: The `in` operator is the only test to really check if the `key` exists. For `var obj = {a: undefined}; ` `'a' in obj` is `true`, but `typeof obj['a'] != "undefined"` is `false`. I don't say that `||`  is a wrong solution. I just say that your statement at the beginning of answer is wrong and should be corrected. Whether `||`  will work or not depends on the usecase.

Comment: @t.niese thank you, I agree with you it was a false statement! fixed the post